# Async loaded partial view scripts initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial

On my control panel web page in ASP.NET MVC 3 site, a user can see his existing projects (its a site for designer portfolio), and can press a button to add a new project to the library.

A markup and the javascript dependencies for this particular "project adding functionality" are referenced in a partial view razor code.

Whenever a user click a button on a page, I retrieve the contents of the partial view and place them on the bottom of the page and call jQuery UI `.dialog` on a generated div to display a project editing/adding popup.

But how can I invoke a logic to initialize validation and other logic (click handlers for example) that is referencing elements in this partial view content? (Due to this I can't just initialize everything at document ready)

Do I just hardcode some function in a linked js (for example initProjectEditing()) and call it from the code that initializes the popup, or is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the good way is to use [Jquery widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/widget/) . This thing allows
 you to define logic for your component in 1 place and then reuse it
 whenever you need.

- You can create "add new project" Jquery widget.
- Define all functionality concerning "add new project" in this widget
  (validation, event handlers, etc.)
- Reference all javascripts needed
  for "add new project" directly from main view and not in partial view
  as you do now. You can create spetial partial view with such
  references if you need to reuse it in different places.
- After your "add new project" partial view was loaded and dialog was
  shown, just init "add new project" widget with loaded html.